# How to add/remove menu item programmatically?

Tags: joomla-2.5, menu-item

I have a Joomla v2.5.14 application and I'm in a situation that I need to hide a menu item from the users based on a database value, basically what I need is to hide the menu item based on a condition.

My question is, where's the right place to perform this? and how to do it?

Comment: Please update to Joomla to 2.5.28. You're leaving yourself **and your users** vulnerable. Luckily you haven't provided a link to your site, else it could take anyone less than 15 minute to hack. Please then consider migrating to Joomla 3.x

Comment: Once you've updated to 2.5.28 remember you also need the Session Hardening Patch which can be downloaded from: https://docs.joomla.org/Security_hotfixes_for_Joomla_EOL_versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the menu option has a suitable CSS selector e.g. "item-135", it could be hidden via CSS.

You could create a custom HTML module to add the appropriate code to the applicable page(s). Set the custom HTML module position to "debug" or similar if your template has this option (as the debug module position is less likely to have any margins or padding associated with it).

Install and enable the [Regular Labs Sourcerer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sourcerer) plugin or similar so the code is not stripped from your Custom HTML Module.

In the Custom HTML Module, your code will look something like this:

```
{source}
  <?php
    if ([some condition]) {
      $document = JFactory::getDocument();
      $style = '.item-135 {display: none;}';
      $document->addStyleDeclaration ($style);
    }
  ?>
{/source}
```

Comment: I don't know if this was an update since J2.5, but from:  https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/sourcerer/tutorial:

"_Sourcerer already creates the $document (or $doc) object for you when it is needed. So you do not have to initialize this yourself._" [Reduced snippet](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/26645/12352)