# How to Completely Remake (Delete, Then Add) Menu Items Through Joomla Framework

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, joomla-framework-1.x

A couple of previous questions have touched on this topic ([how to add menu items](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5104/programmatically-add-menu-item-in-component), [how to hide menu items](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15787/how-to-add-remove-menu-item-programmatically)), but I'm trying to figure out how to remove or empty a menu and then programmatically refill it. It seems like the task has three parts:

1. **How do you delete an entire menu?** Previous answers to manipulating menu items point to [JNestedTable](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JTableNested.html) for menu manipulation, but I don't see a function for accomplishing this--only for deleting a generic row from a table using a primary key value. I could do this outside of the Joomla Framework using a SQL query, but I suspect that is the wrong approach (because it will mess up the lft and rgt values):

   DELETE FROM menu WHERE menutype='name'
2. **How do you add menu items?** [I believe this was answered here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5104/programmatically-add-menu-item-in-component), but any other thoughts?
3. **Once the menu is deleted and new menu items are added, how do you rebuild the menu?** I know you can rebuild menus from the backend, but how can you do it programmatically?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably best looking at `com_menu` and studying how core Joomla does it.

For deleting and adding entire menus, you can see the relevant functions at `\administrator\components\com_menus\models\menu.php`.

Here there is a function called `delete`, to which you pass an array of menu IDs, and it deletes them one at a time in a foreach loop.  It's well commented, though does have the ominous comment `// TODO: Delete the menu associations - Menu items and Modules` at the end.

It also has a function to `save` here, which creates or edits menus.  Here  you pass the relevant data to match the fields at `administrator\components\com_menus\models\forms\menu.xml`.  Send it an id of 0 if it is a new menu.

The rebuild function is found under `\administrator\components\com_menus\models\item.php`.  This isn't well annotated, but it looks like JTable has a function for rebuilding.

This file also has the `save` function for menu items, which works in a similar way to the way the menu one worked.